# My flutter app doesn't render the UI after a restart in release/profile mode

Tags: flutter, dart

I've built a flutter app for my client with Dhiwise ( figma to flutter tool ) and the ui renders well in debug mode but on release / profile mode it renders well only first time and after restart it doesn't render at all.

It only renders the navigation bar of the app that I've added since Dhiwise didn't add a navigation bar , this problem I've been facing it for weeks, please help

here's my main.dart that contains the navigation bar

```dart
void main()  {
  // WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp.router(
      routerConfig: router,
...
    );
  }
}

class Navigation extends HookWidget {
  const Navigation({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
...
    return Scaffold(
      body: children[index.value],
      bottomNavigationBar: NavigationBar(
        onDestinationSelected: (i) => index.value = i,
        labelBehavior: NavigationDestinationLabelBehavior.onlyShowSelected,
        destinations: [
          NavigationDestination(
            icon: Icon(Icons.home),
            label: 'Home',
          ),
          ...
```

and that's the first page that's not rendered

```dart
class HomeVonePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Column(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                CustomAppBar(
                  height: 49,
                  title: Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 24, right: 24),
                    child: Column(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: [
                        Align(
                          alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                          child: Padding(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 45),
                            child: Text(
                              "Welcome back!",
                              overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                              textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                              style: AppStyle.txtRobotoMedium12.copyWith(
                                letterSpacing: getHorizontalSize(
                                  0.3,
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        Align(
                          alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                          child: Padding(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                              top: 7,
                            ),
                            child: Text(
                              "Tommy Jason",
                              overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                              textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                              style: AppStyle.txtRobotoBold20WhiteA700.copyWith(
                                letterSpacing: getHorizontalSize(
                                  0.3,
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                  actions: [
                    Card(
                      clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
                      elevation: 0,
                      margin: getMargin(
                        left: 24,
                        right: 24,
                        bottom: 1,
                      ),
                      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                        side: BorderSide(
                          color: ColorConstant.whiteA70026,
                          width: getHorizontalSize(
                            1,
                          ),
                        ),
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(
                          getHorizontalSize(
                            16,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      child: Container(
                        height: getSize(
                          48,
                        ),
                        width: getSize(
                          48,
                        ),
                        padding: getPadding(
                          all: 12,
                        ),
                        decoration: AppDecoration.outlineWhiteA70026.copyWith(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadiusStyle.circleBorder17,
                        ),
                        child: Stack(
                          alignment: Alignment.topRight,
                          children: [
                            CustomImageView(
                              svgPath: ImageConstant.imgNotification,
                              height: getSize(
                                24,
                              ),
                              width: getSize(
                                24,
                              ),
                              alignment: Alignment.center,
                              margin: getMargin(
                                all: 12,
                              ),
                            ),
                            Align(
                              alignment: Alignment.topRight,
                              child: Container(
                                height: getSize(
                                  8,
                                ),
                                width: getSize(
                                  8,
                                ),
                                margin: getMargin(
                                  left: 27,
                                  top: 13,
                                  right: 13,
                                  bottom: 27,
                                ),
                                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                  color: ColorConstant.indigo90001,
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(
                                    getHorizontalSize(
                                      4,
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  border: Border.all(
                                    color: ColorConstant.teal400,
                                    width: getHorizontalSize(
                                      1,
                                    ),
                                    strokeAlign: strokeAlignOutside,
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
                Container(
                  height: getVerticalSize(
                    195,
                  ),
                  width: getHorizontalSize(
                    327,
                  ),
                  margin: getMargin(
                    top: 26,
                  ),
                  child: Stack(
                    alignment: Alignment.center,
                    children: [
                      Align(
                        alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                        child: Container(
                          height: getVerticalSize(
                            118,
                          ),
                          width: getHorizontalSize(
                            255,
                          ),
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            color: ColorConstant.blueGray90087,
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(
                              getHorizontalSize(
                                16,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      Align(
                        alignment: Alignment.center,
                        child: Card(
                          clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
                          elevation: 0,
                          margin: EdgeInsets.all(0),
                          color: ColorConstant.indigo900,
                          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(
                              getHorizontalSize(
                                16,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                          child: Container(
                            height: getVerticalSize(
                              190,
                            ),
                            width: getHorizontalSize(
                              327,
                            ),
                            decoration: AppDecoration.fillIndigo900.copyWith(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadiusStyle.circleBorder17,
                            ),
                            child: Stack(
                              alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                              children: [
                                Align(
                                  alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
                                  child: Container(
                                    padding: getPadding(
                                      all: 20,
                                    ),
                                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                      image: DecorationImage(
                                        image: Svg(ImageConstant.imgMaskgroup),
                                        fit: BoxFit.cover,
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                    child: Column(
                                      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                                      crossAxisAlignment:
                                          CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                      mainAxisAlignment:
                                          MainAxisAlignment.start,
                                      children: [
                                        Container(
                                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(
                                              getHorizontalSize(
                                                16,
                                              ),
                                            ),
                                          ),
                                          child: Row(
                                            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                                            children: [
                                              CustomImageView(
                                                svgPath: ImageConstant
                                                    .imgComputerWhiteA700,
                                                height: getVerticalSize(
                                                  24,
                                                ),
                                                width: getHorizontalSize(
                                                  32,
                                                ),
                                                radius: BorderRadius.circular(
                                                  getHorizontalSize(
                                                    12,
                                                  ),
                                                ),
                                                margin: getMargin(
                                                  top: 4,
                                                  bottom: 3,
                                                ),
                                              ),
                                              CustomImageView(
                                                svgPath: ImageConstant
                                                    .imgVolumeWhiteA700,
                                                height: getSize(
                                                  32,
                                                ),
                                                width: getSize(
                                                  32,
                                                ),
                                                radius: BorderRadius.circular(
                                                  getHorizontalSize(
                                                    16,
                                                  ),
                                                ),
                                                margin: getMargin(
                                                  left: 8,
                                                ),
                                              ),
                                            ],
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                        Padding(
                                          padding: getPadding(
                                            top: 34,
                                            bottom: 40,
                                          ),
                                          child: Text(
                                            "****   ****   ****   1121",
                                            overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                                            textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                                            style: AppStyle.txtRobotoBold14
                                                .copyWith(
                                              letterSpacing: getHorizontalSize(
                                                0.3,
                                              ),
                                            ),
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                      ],
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                                Align(
                                  alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                                  child: Container(
                                    margin: getMargin(
                                      top: 126,
                                    ),
                                    padding: getPadding(
                                      left: 20,
                                      top: 14,
                                      right: 20,
                                      bottom: 14,
                                    ),
                                    decoration:
                                        AppDecoration.fillTeal400.copyWith(
                                      borderRadius:
                                          BorderRadiusStyle.customBorderBL16,
                                    ),
                                    child: Row(
                                      mainAxisAlignment:
                                          MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                                      crossAxisAlignment:
                                          CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                      children: [
                                        Padding(
                                          padding: getPadding(
                                            bottom: 5,
                                          ),
                                          child: Text(
                                            "\$15,365.00",
                                            overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                                            textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                                            style: AppStyle
                                                .txtRobotoBold24WhiteA700,
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                        CustomImageView(
                                          svgPath: ImageConstant.imgGroup18274,
                                          height: getVerticalSize(
                                            26,
                                          ),
                                          width: getHorizontalSize(
                                            43,
                                          ),
                                          margin: getMargin(
                                            top: 1,
                                            bottom: 7,
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                      ],
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                Container(
                  margin: getMargin(
                    top: 27,
                  ),
                  padding: getPadding(
                    left: 21,
                    top: 15,
                    right: 21,
                    bottom: 15,
                  ),
                  decoration: AppDecoration.fillGray50.copyWith(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadiusStyle.circleBorder17,
                  ),
                  child: Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: [
                      Column(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                        children: [
                          CustomImageView(
                            svgPath: ImageConstant.imgMoneyrecive,
                            height: getSize(
                              24,
                            ),
                            width: getSize(
                              24,
                            ),
                          ),
                          Padding(
                            padding: getPadding(
                              top: 10,
                            ),
                            child: Text(
                              "Deposit",
                              overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                              textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                              style:
                                  AppStyle.txtRobotoMedium12Indigo900.copyWith(
                                letterSpacing: getHorizontalSize(
                                  0.3,
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                      Padding(
                        padding: getPadding(
                          left: 33,
                          bottom: 2,
                        ),
                        child: Column(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                          children: [
                            CustomImageView(
                              svgPath: ImageConstant.imgCall,
                              height: getSize(
                                24,
                              ),
                              width: getSize(
                                24,
                              ),
                            ),
                            Padding(
                              padding: getPadding(
                                top: 9,
                              ),
                              child: Text(
                                "Transfers",
                                overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                                textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                                style: AppStyle.txtRobotoMedium12Indigo900
                                    .copyWith(
                                  letterSpacing: getHorizontalSize(
                                    0.3,
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                      Padding(
                        padding: getPadding(
                          left: 28,
                          bottom: 1,
                        ),
                        child: Container(
                          color: Colors.white,
                          child: Column(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                            children: [
                              CustomImageView(
                                svgPath: ImageConstant.imgMoneyrecive,
                                height: getSize(
                                  24,
                                ),
                                width: getSize(
                                  24,
                                ),
                              ),
                              Padding(
                                padding: getPadding(
                                  top: 9,
                                ),
                                child: Text(
                                  "Withdraw",
                                  overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                                  textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                                  style: AppStyle.txtRobotoMedium12Indigo900
                                      .copyWith(
                                    letterSpacing: getHorizontalSize(
                                      0.3,
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      Padding(
                        padding: getPadding(
                          left: 40,
                          bottom: 1,
                        ),
                        child: Column(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                          children: [
                            CustomImageView(
                              svgPath: ImageConstant.imgGrid,
                              height: getSize(
                                24,
                              ),
                              width: getSize(
                                24,
                              ),
                            ),
                            Padding(
                              padding: getPadding(
                                top: 9,
                              ),
                              child: Text(
                                "More",
                                overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                                textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                                style: AppStyle.txtRobotoMedium12Indigo900
                                    .copyWith(
                                  letterSpacing: getHorizontalSize(
                                    0.3,
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: getPadding(
                    top: 25,
                  ),
                  child: Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: [
                      Padding(
                        padding: getPadding(
                          top: 1,
                        ),
                        child: Text(
                          "Today, Mar 20",
                          overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                          textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                          style: AppStyle.txtRobotoBold14Gray600.copyWith(
                            letterSpacing: getHorizontalSize(
                              0.3,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      Spacer(),
                      Padding(
                        padding: getPadding(
                          bottom: 1,
                        ),
                        child: Text(
                          "All transactions",
                          overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                          textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                          style: AppStyle.txtRobotoMedium14Indigo900.copyWith(
                            letterSpacing: getHorizontalSize(
                              0.3,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      CustomImageView(
                        svgPath: ImageConstant.imgArrowrightBlack900,
                        height: getSize(
                          14,
                        ),
                        width: getSize(
                          14,
                        ),
                        margin: getMargin(
                          left: 4,
                          top: 2,
                          bottom: 2,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: getPadding(
                    top: 21,
                  ),
                  child: ListView.separated(
                    physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                    shrinkWrap: true,
                    separatorBuilder: (context, index) {
                      return Padding(
                        padding: getPadding(
                          top: 20.0,
                          bottom: 20.0,
                        ),
                        child: SizedBox(
                          width: getHorizontalSize(
                            327,
                          ),
                          child: Divider(
                            height: getVerticalSize(
                              1,
                            ),
                            thickness: getVerticalSize(
                              1,
                            ),
                            color: ColorConstant.gray100,
                          ),
                        ),
                      );
                    },
                    itemCount: 3,
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                      return ListlocationItemWidget();
                    },
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I'm not getting any errors only warning for deprecated `window`
`Size size = WidgetsBinding.instance.window.physicalSize;`

and here are screenshots!

[image: A screenshot]
[[image: Another screenshot(https://i.stack.imgur.com/508rc.png)]

I've tried adding `extendbody:true` in Scaffold and didn't change anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to run release using this command to see errors in your console `Flutter run --release` or you can run this command `Flutter logs` and open the app this may help.

I faced same issue before and I just disabled some UI components to see if it will work and it was sizes issue.

Comment: Super Thanks for that , it was my size issue too and fixed it

Answer (score 0):

For Flutter-Dart

You have to check widgets and its parent widgets but maybe its not fix your issue.

**So check this steps. Each step is different, do not use them all together.**

- **1. check widgets** *

It happens most commonly when you are using Expended widget out side the Column or Row.
To solve this error, your child widget must have the expected parent widget. Some of the widget and their parent widgets are:

[image]

Make sure to have the right parent for all the widgets using this Table, and you will be good to go!

- ***2. Use extendBody property of Scaffold widget***

> return Scaffold(
> extendBody: true,
> ...

- ***3. Size configuration***

Your widget dimensions may not have been initialized yet while your screen layout is loading. Try to print logs of size values in debugging. it may not be initialized or 0 value.

- ***4. Dependency injection***

if you are using some dependencies to get size of device or some dependency management packages (As getx) try this steps.

1. Disable packets from fetching data from classes.
2. Define the screen size and dimensions in the page or class where you get the error.
3. Temporarily comment out functions such as `size = sizepackage.getScreenwidth()`; because moving data into the class may cause errors.
4. get size dimensions from intra-class variables. like width = size.width. You can use MediaQueryData with context temporarily.

So example:

if you have Dimensions class for managing your device size.
use like this.

```
final width = Dimensions().getSize().width;
```

not like this:

```
_dimensions = Get.find... or Bloc or other Provider package
final width = _dimensions.getSize().width;
```

***5. if your issue is fixed with this way put some func. to wait provider to load size configuration***. How:

- - extend class with WidgetsBindingObserver
- - put this initState `WidgetsBinding.instance!.addObserver(this);`
- - watch is loaded size veriables or changed variables with `void didChangeMetrics() {`
- - Update your dimensions with their latest version. and refresh state in `didChangeMetrics()` func.

  **setState(() {
  previousSize = newSize;
  });**
- - do not forget to remove WidgetsBindingObserver in `dispose()` func.
    **WidgetsBinding.instance!.removeObserver(this);**

**visit here for details:**

[my medium blog](https://medium.com/@mkiziltay/fluter-ui-error-after-release-release-mode-render-bugs-0cff7a0e72b4)

or

[github blog](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/126820)